# React set input value to object property not editable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm setting the value of an input to a property on an object (from the state). I have an `onChange` event to update the state. However, when I try to type, it doesn't actually update in the input. If I don't use an object and just have a string, it works fine. How can I fix this?

[Demo of the issue](https://playcode.io/911220)
My code:

```js
import React from "react";

export function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    test: "hello"
  });
  
  const change = (e) => {
    data.test = e.target.value;
    setData(data);
  };

  return <input value={data.test} onChange={change}></input>;
}
```

Comment: You can look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the comment by [Aman Sadhwani](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72588520/react-set-input-value-to-object-property-not-editable#comment128224472_72588520), I used spread syntax to update the state without modifying the original object.

```js
const change = (e) => {
    setData({
        ...data,
        test: e.target.value
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Aman Sadhwani. Use Spread operator to update the state.

```
import React from "react";

export function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({
    test: "hello"
  });
  
  const change = (e) => {
    setData({
    ...data
    test:e.target.value
    });
  };

  return <input value={data.test} onChange={change}></input>;
}
```